# synchronize joomla mysql and powerbuilder sql anywhere database

Tags: mysql, joomla, powerbuilder, sqlanywhere

Hallo!
I need to synchronize 2 Databases. I have a Windows 2000 Server with Xampp (schoolserver).
Do you know some ways to realize this?

I thought following:
1.Write the data in the php script or c# script
2. let something like a cronjob(dont know the windows form) run and check both databases.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need to go one-way (master-slave) or do you need for each to be able to change data?

Comment: i need to go 2 way exchanging

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Powerbuilder? Powerbuilder has a feature called [data pipeline](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37774.1200/html/apptech/apptech196.htm) that you can use to migrate/pipe data between tables. The source table & destination don't have to be in the same  DBMS. In your case you could pipe your data from mysql to sqlanywhere & vice versa.

Have you considered using a bcp Utility to export the data then import it to the destination database?